# Get readable output from RFID scanner for encrypted PDF417 barcode

Tags: barcode, rfid, pdf417

I am testing a CipherLab handheld RFID reader to scan a driver license which has an encrypted PDF417 barcode with binary data.

When I scan the barcode, I get the below string values, which obviously means nothing. Is there a way to set the scanner to not return the barcode text "as is", but rather return the barcode as a base64 string or hex string.

Return string from barcode scan:

> › E��¥—IÉ?K ×[´
> =î®—æ~$Œ§òè>–Çº9?vƒÛîÎH†dò{EÑÆÃ:ô&œ ÓÀ
> ø.ÖÊ\ñ…Ç@ÇÅ|'Å%f ö€Ïö€dð    E¢öJAN¨µL¤Shwšr"ÜAœ@-¸;—*L>ûlH;'ômƒJ²ê
> ïB»`Î‡#{jmÛXaùÛwÛø‰¸žZ»t±~ -K¦F€©òW-Í¶˜\8q®'0eyÀV@"~AÓ×ÕP„]žsáŠ T!ÿ½I±$¿wf¤Nä¢ÆS¯Ë,Åï]¯(p&°ë8éõ™ª-°· .$Ô¹ÃbÞ    H/¥å0ž·F}ñ pÎ( üïê5Þ�åPdâb"˜Ñyc–á!D ;ÊX¦Ý!àï`‡og ßÓø-D¥ª®&ÜÖÃ=Ü‡‚Ô•¸6?ïþi«^^†ÃzÛÏMä!Ý®. :ô@ôÃ[Üv$YÔÄnÜ'¤¯ƒ"²    kÖ‰ 0c‚&¼Gð7èé]·Í"ßáúÿ?ÀÓ™ÿÎÔn°åy¸(ÜÓŸ¹+Ÿø½1•Üt½Š¥é�f@5ëì¦f¶*üñ`ýÒ>ˆ¯JíóRqMÿ\ž¹|i`/T£04¸¬~É¡aµˆßg   wÙÌÿêú3fÒÇßÀáˆ½ÅÕ°;üð¾AÖP²3ÿ—‡V€§R€o;& »"¼ÔÃùÀ¤9À�wZß!<›ŠõU?!o+"¡©ùcœÒÄ Ö*ªjšé©Zkkæ¸u!{íxûñ{ñanõ ®|Á'LãBµ!í«xE:ÖsãÉ7„½øND'ƒôû—$âåÂ5öˆóòŠÐ0ýêYg#ùçƒƒPíÂ\îpm¸‹')¨ƒœƒ4Ó+Šš$bqÖ¿xÜL

The barcode I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: That obviously depends on your scanner hardware (which probably will only return the bits it reads from the barcode) and the software interpreting that result (which seems to write out plain ASCII and doesn't convert to base64). But as you mentioned neither of them, how do you suppose anyone could help? And what does that all have to do with RFID?

Comment: The printed representation of the bytes read means nothing really because that depends on the encoding used. Similar to UTF-8 vs ANSI: if you read the exact same bytes and miss the encoding, it's meaningless. So you can encode in base64, hex or print as unicode - you need to know the data structure used.  You probably ASSUME that the data in encoded in plain ascii. This is obviously not the case.

Comment: @MyICQ we already have a decoding system in place which works, it takes in a hex string and returns all the info in the barcode. The problem is we would like to get the results from the scanner as hex string or even byte array, instead of the gibberish. But like derpirscher mentioned, I believe it's a scanner config / setup, thanks anyhow

Comment: @deanwilliammills the scanner will return bytes anyway. I believe some system receives the data and prints it. Depending on the implementation of that, can't you just do a `hex()` conversion to view it as such ? Remember that receiving `ABC` represented as `414243` as hex is not the same as receiving `414243`, which represents as `343134323433` hex.

Comment: To get the encrypted text, you have to decrypt the binary data. Do you know the decryption algorithm or method? For example, I created a [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/south-africa-driving-license/) to decode and decrypt South African driving license which is encoded in PDF417.